# Could not access Cordova plugin from the Ionic app converted from Angular

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have converted my angular app to Ionic referring [this article](https://dev.to/a_shokn/how-to-convert-your-existing-angular-project-to-an-ionic-app-465l). The app runs fine in my android mobile. Now I have the requirement to use the [screenrecord plugin](https://github.com/kwangmeng/ionic-screen-recorder). I could see the plugin in 'dependencies' in package.json. However, when I try to access the plugin, I'm getting the following error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cordova-plugin-screenrecord' in 'C:\NPEC\visitor-fe - Copy\src\app\pages\questionnaire'
resolve 'cordova-plugin-screenrecord' in 'C:\NPEC\visitor-fe - Copy\src\app\pages\questionnaire'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: C:\NPEC\visitor-fe - Copy\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/pages/questionnaire)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in C:/NPEC/visitor-fe - Copy
        using description file: C:\NPEC\visitor-fe - Copy\package.json (relative path: .)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: C:\NPEC\visitor-fe - Copy\package.json (relative path: ./cordova-plugin-screenrecord)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\NPEC\visitor-fe - Copy\cordova-plugin-screenrecord doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              C:\NPEC\visitor-fe - Copy\cordova-plugin-screenrecord.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx...
```

I'm using Angular - 11.0.2, typescript - 4.0.5, Ionic - 6.12.3

Please let me know how to solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Try this  ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screenrecord, npm i cordova-plugin-screenrecord.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoDesenvolvedor. I used `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screenrecord --save` It worked!